# Stripe Canadian Tax Integration

Tags: integration, stripe-payments

I would like to use Stripe for my Canadian e-shop. The problem is that I need to calculate a TAX based on the billing address.

Is it possible to use the embedded Stripe Checkout form where a customer enters a billing address and somehow the tax is calculated before the payment is done?

PS: All items have the same tax, so no need to calculate it separately.

Answer (score 2):

The payment is actually made using your server-side code, not Checkout itself. So after you pass the payment info (i.e., the card) to Stripe in Checkout, you'll get a token in return, and that will be submitted to your server-side code along with anything else you want.

At that point, you can check the address, calculate the tax, and then request a payment in the adjusted amount.

Hope that helps!
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.